# Access Json fields in body of message

Tags: javascript, json

I have below line in my Controller class:

```
this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", message);
```

message is an arrayList. In a jsp file I open a socket and subscribe to "topic/greetings". I'm trying to access a field in the body of the message sent by Controller:
so I'm doing this:

```
var stompClient = null;
var socket = new SockJS('/gs-guide-websocket');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
   stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function(message) {
     console.log(message.body);
   }
}
```

This prints below line on console of browser:

```
[  
  {  
    "_id":{  
      "timestamp":1487493075,
      "machineIdentifier":1371548,
      "processIdentifier":-28904,
      "counter":16629528,
      "date":1487493075000,
      "time":1487493075000,
      "timeSecond":1487493075
    },
    "name":"Alex",
    "age":25
  }
]
```

I want to access field name of that object.
`message.body.name` prints undefined.
I also tried:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(message.body);
console.log(obj.name);
```

or

```
console.log(obj["name"]);
```

but they are all undefined.

*UPDATE:*

I'd seen [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json), but my mistake was trying:

```
var obj = message.body;
console.log(obj[0]);
```

instead of this one:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(message.body);
console.log(obj[0].name);
```

Comment: `console.log(obj[0].name)` let me know if that works

Comment: That worked. thanks. @DenIsahac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please note that `message.body` is an array so use this:

```
console.log(obj[0]["name"]);
```